# How to connect to Smileupps Couchdb with MyCouch and C#?

Tags: c#, uwp, connection, couchdb, mycouch

I may be wrong by the way I'm going about this, but I'm trying to connect to an online database that I'm hosting on Smileupps. I'm using CouchDB, and in my program I'm using MyCouch to try to communicate with the DB. Am I mistaken in doing this? How do I write a query to check if it works?

```
 public void Connection()
    {
        using (var client = new MyCouchClient("https://couchdb-68effd.smileupps.com/_utils/", "dks-calc"))
        {
            // querys go here I assume
        }

    }
```

I'm not sure if I should be connecting on the MainPage.xaml.cs or the Client.cs that was generated with MyCouch.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Falkf.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you connect to CouchDB, don`t use the GUI link. Test something like this :

```
new MyCouchClient("https://couchdb-68effd.smileupps.com/", "dks-calc")
```